# Required Field Validator on FileUpload Control

Tags: asp.net

I have a form in which I have two textboxes and one fileupload control, I am using required field validator on one textbox and on Fileupload control, When I am clicking the submit button, its disabling the fileupload control and not showing any validation for it.

I also have second button for Cancel, clicking on which redirects to previous page, when I am clicking this button its also disabling the fileuploadcontrol.
Below is my code

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFileupload" ValidationGroup="validate" runat="server"
                                                ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


  <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubj" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                                ID="rfvSubject" ControlToValidate="txtSubj" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                                EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="* required" ValidationGroup="validate" />


<asp:Button ID="btnupload" runat="server" Text="Send" ValidationGroup="validate"
                    OnClick="btnupload_Click">
                <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btncancel_Click"
                    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **no** ValidadationGroup:

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fupDocument" runat="server" Width="100%" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="* Required Field" ControlToValidate="fupDocument">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I tried and work it.